# Array: subtract by row

Tags: r

How can I subtract a vector of each row in a array?

```
a <- array(1:8, dim=c(2,2,2))
a
, , 1

      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

, , 2

       [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8
```

Using apply gives me:

```
apply(a,c(1,2), '-',c(1,5))
, , 1

      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    0    1

, , 2

      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    3
[2,]    2    3
```

What I am trying to get is:

```
, , 1

      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0   -2
[2,]    1   -1

, , 2

      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    2
[2,]    5    3
```

Thanks in advance for any hints

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `sweep` to operate on a particular margin of the array: rows are the second dimension (margin).

```
sweep(a,MARGIN=2,c(1,5),FUN="-")
```

Answer (score 4):

```
> library (plyr)
> aaply(a, 1, "-", c(1,5) )
, ,  = 1


X1  1  2
  1 0 -2
  2 1 -1

, ,  = 2


X1  1 2
  1 4 2
  2 5 3
```

Comment: thanks for this solution too, does exactly what I am looking for as well

Answer (score 3):

Use [`scale`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/scale.html) to subtract either the mean or a specified vector from each row, and then divide it either by the standard deviation or a specified vector.

For your example:
  `scale(a, c(1,5), FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

```
> a - rep(c(1,5),each=2)
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0   -2
[2,]    1   -1

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    2
[2,]    5    3
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, is there no way to go over a array by row?